# Usage of ‘at least’

Tags: word-choice

Today I received an email from Skype, letting me know thus:

**“Notice that Xbox now requires that you sign in at least every 5 years to keep your gamertag active”**

This strikes me as odd, as a native speaker. To say to sign in ‘*at least* every five years’ would imply that it be a requirement to sign in every five years *or greater*, would it not? Does the above sentence somehow mean the opposite if what it means literally?

Thanks.

Edit: I just came to think that perhaps they had meant to say ‘at least **once** every five years’, but what they have written then seems like a mistake to me instead.

Comment: No, the interpretation you've suggested strikes me as obviously wrong.  "Every five years" is a frequency.  Imagine you substituted "at least annually."  Would you still argue for that interpretation?

Comment: @Casey I suppose ‘at least once per year’ is how I’d hear that, even though *anually* and *once per year* are not synonymous. Even then, ‘at least every five years’ doesn’t sound right, as stated above, which is why my interpretation was such a stretch.

Comment: @Casey To correct myself in the post, I suppose it would be better to interpret it as ‘at least once in every five years’. Otherwise, this use of ‘at least’ definitely appears to be incorrect (as, if five years were the least, everybody playing XBox more than once within five years would have lost their gamertag, as I read it).

Comment: What I'm telling you is that "every five years" should be analyzed like a single unit.  Like "annually."

Comment: @Casey Sorry, but if you say that ‘at least annually’ can’t work, then why can ‘at least every five years’?

Comment: What I am saying is that "at least annually" means "no less frequently than once a year," and "every five years" works the same way.

Comment: The question, after the edit, contains its own answer: yes, to accurately convey its intended meaning, the sentence should have contained *once* (but the context makes it easy to figure out what the intended meaning is, in spite of its being the opposite of the literal one). There isn't anything significant that a formal answer would be likely to add to that.

Answer (score 1):

Context is very important in this case. You are required to sign in at least once every five years, so the least you can do to achieve that goal is to sign in once. Therefore "at least" is being used to describe that once in five year requirement. Don't get me wrong, it would have saved a lot of headache if they just added once, but it is technically correct.